# Is it possible to set a message after the permission requests when installing apk(Android)?

Tags: android, apk, android-permissions

Is it possible to set a message after the permission requests when installing apk (Android)?

Just right after the permission dialog is showed, and the user selects if he allows it yes/no, and after that show a custom message? is it possible to do that?
before the application itself is installed.

Comment: Your code only runs when user installs your app, Is it possible before installation? of course NOT

Comment: @FarshadTmb then how could I show a custom message before the user installs my app?

Comment: Before installation you are not there to do something my friend !

Comment: @FarshadTmb i think just don know it

Comment: It's fine, That's why permissions exist, you request for permissions, user accepts, in that scenario your code is allowed to run, before that you have no control.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to set a message after the permission requests when installing apk(Android)?

No. You are welcome to show a message if and when the user chooses to run your app.